# jquery trigger is not passing radio button value

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, triggers

I have a radio button (Yes, No) and input text box.
If the user press no, the input field will be disabled and jquery .triger('change') for the ajax form submission (wherein i have initiated ajax

```
$('#form-id').change(function(){
....
});
```

with the above function)

[image]

But when yes is checked, input becomes active and user can enter value and press submit button as usual. The above ajax change function very well detect the change as the user will type and lose focus. so no issues with this part.

[image]

My problem is when the user check no, the isset($_post['radio_no']) parameter in the php form submisssion is shown blank. Instead I need it to be shown value='No'.

All my efforts are going in vein. Can anyone help me out.

My Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value=='No'){
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").prop('disabled', true);
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").val('0').trigger('change');
    } else {
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").val(''); 
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").prop('disabled', false);
    }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer myself by modifying the above Jquery. My final Jquery is as below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('input').on('ifClicked', function (event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value=='No'){
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").prop('disabled', true);
    $('input:radio[name=radio][value=Yes]:checked').prop('checked', false).iCheck('update'); // Added
    $('input:radio[name=radio]').filter('[value=No]').prop('checked', true); // Added
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").val('0').change();
    } else {
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").val(''); 
    $(this).closest('body').find("input[data-value=" + this.name + "][type=text]").prop('disabled', false);
    }
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like tweaking the PHP side of things might be the easiest way to go here...

```
if (empty($_POST['radio_no'])) $_POST['radio_no'] = 'No';
```

If the PHP approach isn't an option, respond and I'll offer a front-end solution for you.  It's just more work.

Comment: Hi @James Allen, This doesn't help. Actually there is another instance checking for empty bit. So do you have any other suggestion to fix it. Thanks